# Java order of class fields and methods in singleton

Tags: java, mysql, singleton, connection-pooling

I have a surprising problem that any amount of Googling is not helping. I was hoping I can clarify here.

I declared a Java singleton for connection pooling my JDBC/MySQL DB using eager initialization like so:

```
public class SomeConnectionPool
{
   private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger (SomeConnectionPool.class.getName());
   private static SomeDataSource sDS = null;
   private static SomeConnectionPool sCP = new SomeConnectionPool ();

   private SomeConnectionPool ()
   {
     // Configure DataSource, connect to DB
      sDS = new SomeDataSource (config);
   }

   public static SomeConnectionPool getInstance ()
   {
      return sCP;
   }

   public static SomeDataSource getDataSource ()
   {
      return sDS;
   }
}
```

In my application, I use the singleton like so:

```
SomeDataSource sds = SomeConnectionPool.getInstance ().getDataSource ();
Connection connection = sds.getConnection ();
```

this works as expected.

However, if I change the order of the members in `SomeConnectionPool` class like so:

```
public class SomeConnectionPool
{
   private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger (SomeConnectionPool.class.getName());
   private static SomeConnectionPool sCP = new SomeConnectionPool ();
   private static SomeDataSource sDS = null;

   ... // the rest is the same code as before
}
```

I get a null pointer exception on the line that requests a `getConnection()`. I can see that the connection objects are being allocated on the MySQL DB (`show processlist` lists them).

Does the order of the members really matter? This goes against my previous experience. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand what is going on when a class is being created. When a class is created, its static members are also created, line by line.

**I think the real issue is that you declared `SomeDataSource` as static, when it should not be. However, to explain what is causing the issue, lets keep looking at it.**

In your first example

```
private static SomeDataSource sDS = null;
private static SomeConnectionPool sCP = new SomeConnectionPool ();
```

sDs = null. sCP gets constructed and sDs gets constructed as a result.

When you flip the order, sCP gets constructed, as does sDs. Than the next line sets sDs back to null. You should actually try to avoid initializing statics in constructors for this very reason.

Instead you should have:

```
public class SomeConnectionPool
{
   private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger (SomeConnectionPool.class.getName());
   private static SomeDataSource sDS = new SomeDataSource (config);
   private static SomeConnectionPool sCP = new SomeConnectionPool ();

   private SomeConnectionPool ()
   {
     // Configure DataSource, connect to DB
   }
```

However, a typical singleton pattern doesn't have anything static except for the instance. The purpose is to have instance specific logic, but enforce that there is only ever one version of the instance. For example, a more appropriate singleton would be:

```
public class SomeConnectionPool
{
   private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger (SomeConnectionPool.class.getName());
   private static SomeConnectionPool instance = new SomeConnectionPool ();
   private SomeDataSource sDS = null;

   private SomeConnectionPool ()
   {
     // Configure DataSource, connect to DB
      this.sDs = new SomeDataSource (config);
   }
   public static SomeConnectionPool getInstance ()
   {
     return instance;
   }
   public SomeDataSource getDataSource ()
   {
      return this.sDs;
   }
```

Note the removal of `static` in certain places.

Comment: This is definitely an odd pattern.  There is no instance member data or instance-specific logic, and the "getInstance" call is going to return the same object to all callers (after re-initializing static member sDS).  It seems like the whole class could be made static without changing its behavior, at least as shown?

Comment: @T3am5hark That is true. This is a very odd case. I didn't really notice that. I will edit my answer to show a more proper singleton pattern.

Answer (score 4):

In the first ordering :

```
   private static SomeDataSource sDS = null;
   private static SomeConnectionPool sCP = new SomeConnectionPool ();
```

You first initialize `sDS` to null and then give it a non null value in the constructor of SomeConnectionPool. Therefore it's not null.

In the second ordering :

```
   private static SomeConnectionPool sCP = new SomeConnectionPool ();
   private static SomeDataSource sDS = null;
```

`SomeConnectionPool sCP = new SomeConnectionPool ();` initializes sDS in its constructor, and later SomeDataSource `sDS = null;` resets it to null. That's why you get the null pointer exception (`SomeConnectionPool.getInstance ().getDataSource ();` returns null).

Comment: Thanks for all the eager answers here, but it was a hopeless oversight on my part--I have been looking at this code too long and so I missed the `=null` owing to blindly cutting and pasting. However, the lesson on `static` is well taken--- I got confused with Java's instruction reordering--imagined it had something to do with that. Moderators--I tried deleting this question, but I could not.

Comment: @Sonny It's considered bad practice here to delete a question after you got your answer. The questions asked here and their answers are meant to help future visitors.

Comment: Fair enough @Eran. Thanks for the speedy answer still.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The change makes sense.

`static` initializers and such are run in line order. So before, you had:

1. Set `sDS` to `null` `// sDS is null`
2. `sCP = new SomeConnectionPool();`
3. Go into constructor
4. Set `sDS` to `new SomeDataSource(config);` `// sDS is not null`
5. Exit constructor
6. continue

So your final result is `sDS` is not `null`. But after, you had

1. `sCP = new SomeConnectionPool();`
2. Go into constructor
3. Set `sDS` to `new SomeDataSource(config);` `// sDS is not null`
4. Exit constructor
5. Set `sDS` to `null` `// Now sDS is null`
6. continue

And now `sDS` is `null`.